# How to show deprecated JS code as warning?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make VSCode mark all deprecated vanilla JavaScript methods as warning or error?

VSCode strikes out the deprecated code, but having to go through multiple script files checking each line is not a solution.

Comment: I have the same question. VS Code appears to cross out JS deprecated functions, but VS Code does not show these in the Problems panel with other warnings and errors. Would be nice to figure out how to show these in there.

Answer (score 0):

js can tell you :)

you can use ReportingObserver:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReportingObserver/ReportingObserver

it receives 2 parameters, callback and options object. inside options you can indicate when you want to fire callback.

inside options object you need to have key of "type" which is an array of strings representing the types of report to be collected by this observer.

Available types: deprecation, intervention, and crash (although this last type usually isn't retrievable via a ReportingObserver).